# Tippecanoe optimization and still retaining filtering ability

Tags: mapbox, overlapping-features, vector-tiles, optimization, tippecanoe

I'm trying to optimize our displayed vector tileset in symbollayer (In the mobile SDK). If I'm uploading the geojson as it is, I'm getting very bad performance for a number of 3500 features (Only using Points, nothing else, but the points are rather closely grouped). If I'm using tippecanoe to optimize the tiles, all is working pretty fine performance-wise. However, I'm also attempting to add some kind of filtering by property, and when doing so on the output of the tippecanoe, not all the points that match the filter expression are showing up when zooming out to a small zoom level.

I believe that maybe I'm missing some flag in tippecanoe that could help me in this case, or maybe some other thing that I could do to handle this kind of behavior.

Example geojson:
https://gist.github.com/aviadsteps/6e034097eb9f0fe3c48d021603de583b

When trying

```
tippecanoe -zg -o optimized_layer.mbtiles -l main --drop-densest-as-needed many_features.geojson
```

I get tiles that have great performance, but if I will try to filter on certain features' properties, at a high zoom level, I wouldn't see any point.

And when trying

```
tippecanoe -z16 -Z0 -pf -pk -B 0 -o full_layer.mbtiles -l filters many_features.geojson
```

I get tiles that have relatively bad performance (Especially when zooming out and in), but when filtering on the same features, at the same zoom levels, I'm able to see the points that are matching the filter.

1. Is there a way to get both?
2. In zoom level 0 in optimized_layer.mbtiles, I see only one marker. However I'm pretty sure it is possible to show a little bit more, what do I need to supply to tippecanoe to let it know that it could show more markers on a given zoom level?

Comment: Tippecanoe docs say: _The --drop-densest-as-needed option will make Tippecanoe try dropping what should be the least visible features at each zoom level._ What is dropped (does not exist), cannot be filtered.

Comment: Thanks, but is there an option to retain this in some way while still optimizing? I had some test data that worked pretty good, and I think the reason my example data have bad performance is because the density of some of the markers

Comment: No, because optimizing here means leaving out points.

Comment: I see, but if using --cluster-densest-as-needed, still points are left out?

Comment: When you go to the mountains, you have to decide: either my backpack will be light or I'll put everything into it. You cannot have both.